# Page cannot be displayed after about 10 minutes

Tags: asp.net, response

I have a asp.net 4.0 application. A pop-up window has to do some calculations which run for 1 minutes to about 30 minutes. In one instance where it would come back for some 20 minutes. It displays "page cannot be displayed" on production. where as I get the response properly if I run the same input from my local environment. What could be wrong? I know that the httpRuntime ExecutionTimeout is set to 1hr.

Session state for the website is set to 35 minutes.

Thanks in advance for any advise on this.
Manju.

Comment: what have you done to troubleshoot?  what is "some calculations"? can we see the code?  are there any server errors in the production environment?

Comment: I have tried to trace the issue through IIS logs. That did not have any information relating to response to my request. Checked through the application log and system logs from the server. No clue. Calculations mean - these are some xml files with a lot of financial data and links to other objects in them. in this page we expand all the linked objects and generate the completely expanded XML.

Comment: You shouldn't have a single request for that long. HTTP wasn't designed for that. Instead, kick the job off on the server [using an appropriate tool](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx), then poll the server or use SignalR to check the status.

Comment: I completely agree with that point. This is a legacy application developed ages ago. Now upon the growth of data we are seeing this kind of issues. Just wondering if we can increase this request time out limit and get it through. where to look for.